# Labelling axis elements using imagesc

Tags: matlab, plot, axis-labels

I am projecting a matrix with the positions of cars over time.  The X axis is the time and Y axis corresponds to identity of each car. I have 28 cars detected as shown in y-axis. What i want to do is to label each bar with the corresponding car id rather than the total number of cars detected.

The first row of `all_area_for_visual` contains the Car id detected. I want to label each bar horizontally in the projection with the corresponding elements in the first row of `all_area_for_visual`.  The image of the matrix and projection are shown below. Any help will be appreciated. Code and projections are as shown below.

```
cars_in_field = cell2mat(cars_in_field);
cars_in_garge = cell2mat(cars_in_garge);
cars_in_wkshp = cell2mat(cars_in_wkshp);

all_area_for_visual=cars_in_field+2*cars_in_garge+3*cars_in_wkshp;
all_area_for_visual(1,:) = Ucolumnnames_fpm(1,:);

figure
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet")
xlim([0,250000]);
xlabel('Time (s)')
ylabel('Ant identity')
yticks(1:length(Ucolumnnames_fpm))
yticklabels(Ucolumnnames_fpm(1,:))
```

[image: all_area_for_visual]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
figure
imagesc(transpose(all_area_for_visual));
colormap("jet")
xlim([0,250000]);
xlabel('Time (s)')
yticks([all_area_for_visual(1,:)])
```

Comment: when i do this, i don't see any projections. Its just a blank screen.

Comment: It's working in my computer properly. Btw, why you are using the first row in the imagesec?

Comment: @mmahmud. I solved it. The problem was first i need to add a ytick then followed by ytick label.